# Add numeric value on PDF field using Itext

Tags: kotlin, itext

I am trying to pass a numeric value on a PDF but it passes as String. The issue is that the last line on PDF is used to sum all the values above but because the value is string and not integer this function does not work.

```
val form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true)
val fields = form.formFields 

fields[newFieldName]?.setValue(value.valueAsString)
                                ?.setFont(font)
                                ?.setFontSize(TEXT_SIZE)
```

The problem is the setValue method, but I did not find anything in the documentation about how to pass an Integer value. So how do I pass an integer value?

Edit:

Tried this one but it does not place the value on the field

```
fields[newFieldName]?.setRichText(PdfNumber(2.0))
?.setFont(font)
?.setFontSize(TEXT_SIZE)
```

Edit2: Is there any way to get the embedded function on the acro field in order to edit it and make it consider it on the sum string values also?

Comment: The pdf format only knows string values of acroform text fields. Javascript code attached to fields may enforce only numeric characters but itext does not execute any javascript when setting field values.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. The thing is that when I use Adobe reader to manually write a numeric value the sum function on the last line of the pdf works (4 | 5 | 6 --> 15), so is there any way to do that with itext? Lastly The pdf template that I was given I saw that was created with itextSharp @mkl

Comment: Could you share the template?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not (it is kind of confidential and in Greek) but I can provide you with every detail you. @UladzimirAsipchuk

Comment: Chances are that there is some JavaScript code in the PDF calculating the sum in some event. As said above, iText (core) does not execute any JavaScript when editing the form fields (as it changes them not via a GUI but immediately, the events would not apply directly anyways). Thus, you'll also have to calculate the sum in question and set the sum field yourself.

Comment: @mkl Currently I am migrating from one template of PDF to another so I am trying to copy in bulk 150 PDFs from the old style to the new one. I can calculate the sum and place it in the correct field but if I do that and later down the line I open Adobe reader to input a number most likely the js function will not be able to do "12"(calculated by me, placed it as string) + 5(manual integer input in a row above sum). Correct me if I am wrong and thanks for your time.

Comment: As you cannot share the document in question, I cannot tell.

Comment: @mkl do you have any email where I could send you the document?

Comment: Nick, cf. my stack overflow profile.

Comment: @mkl I just sent you the necessary information on your profile email.

Comment: Ok. I'll look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF format only knows string values of AcroForm text fields. JavaScript code attached to fields may enforce only numeric characters but iText does not execute any JavaScript when setting field values.

Thus, concerning your original question

> The problem is the setValue method, but I did not find anything in the documentation about how to pass an Integer value. So how do I pass an integer value?

There is no such thing as a special iText method for setting *integer* values.

---

In the comments it then turned out that the original question for a integer specific was not the actual issue. Instead:

> The thing is that when I use Adobe reader to manually write a numeric value the sum function on the last line of the pdf works (4 | 5 | 6 --> 15), so is there any way to do that with itext?

So the actual issue is that the calculated field contents are not updated after a change by iText.

The reason for this is that this feature in PDFs is implemented by some JavaScript code in the PDF calculating the sum in case of some event but iText (core) does not execute any JavaScript when editing the form fields (as it changes them not via a GUI but immediately, the events would not apply directly anyways).

Thus, you'll also have to calculate the sum in question and set the sum field yourself.

---

> I can calculate the sum and place it in the correct field but if I do that and later down the line I open Adobe reader to input a number most likely the js function will not be able to do "12"(calculated by me, placed it as string) + 5(manual integer input in a row above sum).

The value of a field is always stored as a string in the PDF. Thus, it should make no difference how that string was set, by iText or by Adobe.

After you shared the PDF, I could have a look at its structure and the JavaScript in it.

Indeed, it is an AcroForm form (not a XFA form!) and the calculation of sum and average occurs in JavaScript functions set as the calculate (**C**) additional action (**AA**) of the respective *total* or *average* field. The fields to sum or average are defined by the field names, e.g. for the field name "1-Place_Total" the script calculates the *total* over the contents of the fields "1-Place_1" .. "1-Place_12".

```js
var srcName = event.target.name;
var srcCategory = srcName.substring(srcName.indexOf("_")+1)
var baseName = srcName.replace("Total","").replace("Average","");
var total = Number(0);
var lastMonth = 0;

for(i=1; i < 13; i++){
    var thisMonth = baseName + i;
    var monthVal = this.getField(thisMonth).value;
    total = Number(total) + Number(monthVal);
    if(monthVal > 0){
        lastMonth = i;
    }
}

if(total == 0){
    event.value = "";
}
else if(srcCategory == "Total"){
    event.value = total;
}
else if(srcCategory == "Average"){
    event.value = total / lastMonth;
}
```

The form field additional action "calculate" is specified as

> A JavaScript action that shall be performed to recalculate the value of this field when that of another field changes. (The name **C** stands for “calculate.”)
>
> *(ISO 32000-1, Table 196 – Entries in a form field’s additional-actions dictionary)*

As the script takes the values immediately from the fields in question (not somewhere special where some other scripts might have stored them), it should suffice for you to manually change an arbitrary field value in the PDF to trigger this function to calculate the sum of all applicable fields, no matter whether the individual field values were set by iText or by Adobe.

Fractional numbers might still be a problem in such a scenario as the decimal separator might be different in the appearance and the field value, but as you asked for a method to set *integer* values, I assume that should not be an issue.

---

<sub>*I have to admit I have not tested this, the answer is based on the specification alone. If you create a proof-of-concept and observe it doesn't work, please share that code, I'll then look into this more deeply.*</sub>

Comment: You are a life saver. After programmatically placing the sum and then manually placing and "Integer" using Adobe Reader the sum got updated and it was indeed correct.

Quick question though, how do I access the PDF's embedded js script?

Comment: *"how do I access the PDF's embedded js script?"* - you can use a tool like Adobe Acrobat or itext RUPS.